# Swift Allow landscape in KINWebBrowserViewController view

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, url, orientation

I have a table and each one is assigned a link. When a row is tapped the link opens in a KINWebBrowserViewController view. I don't want the table to allow landscape but I want the web browser to allow it. How can I do it?

Some Code:

```
    let linkItem = linkLabels[indexPath.row] as String

    let webBrowser = KINWebBrowserViewController()
    let url = NSURL(string: linkItem)
    webBrowser.actionButtonHidden = true
    webBrowser.loadURL(url)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webBrowser, animated: true)
```

All suggestions welcomed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the General - deployment info section of your project in Xcode, tick all the permitted orientations for any screen in your app.

iOS calls the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in the rootmost UIViewController that is visible on the screen. If a VC covers the whole screen, then earlier VCs (further towards the root viewController) do not have that method called.

If your `webBrowser` VC covers the whole screen, then put a method in that:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int { return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue) }
```

If `webBrowser` does not cover the whole screen, and `navigationController` is still showing a navigation bar, then that method will not be called, and the one in `navigationController` will be called instead. So, subclass `UINavigationController`:

```
class CustomNC:UINavigationController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int { 
        if visibleViewController is KINWebBrowserViewController { return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue) }
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    }
}
```

and declare your UINavigationController to be a `CustomNC` instead. I haven't tested the code, it may have typos, but that technique is working for me now.

More explanation: `CustomNC` is a new, cleverer `UINavigationController` that you are just going to invent. You can put the code for that in any swift file in your project. It is just like an existing `UINavigationController`, except it changes behaviour on rotation. So you want it to inherit all the behaviour of UINavigationController, and then just override the rotation bit. This bit does the inheriting:

```
class CustomNC:UINavigationController {
```

and this bit does the overriding:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
```

And you need to tell Xcode that your Root ViewController is a `CustomNC` rather than a plain `UINavigationController`. If you've built the project with a storyboard, you can click the `UINavigationController` to select it, then change its class from `UINavigationController` to `CustomNC` in the `Identity Inspector` tab at the top right of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not really sure what you mean. What is that CustomNC?

Comment: More explanation added.

Comment: Ok thanks. I got it working but when going back to the tableviewcontroller and the KINWebBrowserViewController is in landscape the tableviewcontroller is also in landscape. I only want it in portrait. That is the only time the tableviewcontroller goes to landscape. Any other help?

Comment: I think you'd best post a new question, showing your code.

Comment: Yep. Okay. Here is the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389468/swift-tableviewcontroller-is-in-landscape